# ForEach from a text file with my PS script

Tags: powershell

I was hoping someone would be able to help me add a foreach to my script that pulls hostnames from a text file. I know this is so basic, but I can't make it work. Thank you in advance.

Here is my script:

```
#Days passed from last SEP client update
$Error.Clear();
try {
$res=(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\AV" PatternFileDate).PatternFileDate
 }
catch 
 {
  Write-Host "ERROR: $($Error[0])";
  exit 1;
  }
if ($Error.Count -eq 0) {
 $y1=[int]$res[0]+1970;
 $m1=[int]$res[1]+1;
 $d1=[int]$res[2];
 $stat2 = [string](get-date -uformat "%m %d %Y")
 $t2=$stat2.split(" ")
 $m2=[int]$t2[0];
 $d2=[int]$t2[1];
 $y2=[int]$t2[2];
 $diff=($y2-$y1)*365+($m2-$m1)*30+($d2-$d1);
 write-host "Statistic: $diff";
 write-host "Message: Last SEP client update date: $m1/$d1/$y1";
 exit 0;
 }
write-host "Message: Can't find ""HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\AV\PatternFileDate"" registry value";
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could just clarify a few points: you asked about reading from a text file but your code shows reading from the registry; no text file listed. Also it's not clear what you're ultimately trying to do with this script. You're using casts, so it looks like you have other programming experience. Mentioning the language(s) you have experience with is not necessary but might help in providing PowerShell-specific explanations as a way to relate the differences.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks so much for getting back to me. A few things 1) I used to work on the help desk at R/GA!  2) I actually don't have experience programming but I use SolarWinds to monitor the servers in my environment. SW shows the scripts they run against the servers for the checks. This is their script to check SEP file date. Unfortunately for security reasons I'm unable to run the check from within SW, so I'm setting up a script to run it against servers I have listed in a server.txt file saved to my desktop. 3) Thanks for the welcoming! :)

Comment: So really I would like to do a 

$computer=Get-Content C:\Test\servers.txt
and then tie that into a foreach. 

Oh and one more thank you that I owe you, thanks for making the script readable in my question.

Comment: Hi fellow (former) R/GAer! Contact info in profile if you want to keep in touch. jsaak's answer shows how you could use `Get-Content` with `ForEach-Object` to work on each line of the file; that's probably enough to start, and you can post separate questions if you have trouble with something specific; just be sure to include the code you've tried already (see: [mcve])

Comment: Ya I'll find you on Twitter!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet. Example:

```
Get-Content 'PATH_TO_YOUR_TEXT_FILE' | ForEach-Object {
 $hostname = $_
}
```

The text file should look like this:

```
host1
host2
host3
```

Comment: Thanks Jisaak. !! Appreciate the help!